# Static vector in C++ class can not be found

Tags: c++, vector, static

Fail to link the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class Node {
    static vector<Node*> nodeList;
    int id;
    int value;

  public:
    Node(int);
};

Node::Node(int val) {
    id = nodeList.size();
    value = val;
    nodeList.push_back(this);
}
```

I got error message as the following.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "Node::nodeList", referenced from:
>         Node::Node(int) in test-028e68.o
>     "_main", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The problem appears on the static vector. It seems like that the constructor cannot find the symbol nodeList. I don't know how to initialize it to make the code work.

Comment: put this `vector<Node*> Node::nodeList;`, right after your Node class  declaration

Comment: Thanks, it works now!

Comment: Can you post your `main` function?

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  Adding that line is the solution to the problem in your question.

Comment: When you tried @Carafini 's utterly correct suggestion, did the error message change? You will find that one error can hide other errors. Often an enormous cascade of other errors.

Comment: I've added the complete correct code in the main body of the post. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @winterfly Don't add the solution to the question. If you see the need, create an answer. But do it carefully. Highlight what you changed, why you changed it, and how it solved the problem. That way you leave a legacy for future learners struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks. I've posted my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand the difference between declaration and definition:

```
static vector<Node*> nodeList; // declare static member

vector<Node*> Node::nodeList; // define static member
```

It is similar to the following:

```
class Node {...
   Node(int); // here is you declare 
};

Node::Node() {} // here is you define
```

Comment: Thanks! Working now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new entire code, which makes sense and print out correct answers. The key point is add

```
vector<Node*> Node::nodeList;
```

immediately after the definition of Node.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Node {
    static vector<Node*> nodeList;
    int id;
    int value;

public:
    Node(int);
    void print();
};

vector<Node*> Node::nodeList;

Node::Node(int val) {
    id = nodeList.size();
    value = val;
    nodeList.push_back(this);
}

void Node::print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Node " << nodeList[i]->id << "'s value is " << nodeList[i]->value << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Node n1(1), n2(3);
    n1.print();
    return 0;
}
```